# Post to different URL from a spring controller

Tags: java, spring, rest

I need to post the same request to a different webhook URL what I am getting in my spring controller so that the same operation can be performed on the both server. I am trying to do this for some integration purpose.
Please help.

Thanks,
Vidyakar Sharma.

Answer (score 1):

A browser submit usually goes only to one server. You could write a java script that does an ajax call to the second server.
A second option could be that the first server calls you second server, so your spring controller creates the second http request.

Comment: this is really a nice answer... +1